# Is there any way to resume YouTube API video?

Tags: java, android, youtube

I am writing an simple app for Android using YouTube API - I would like to achieve the state where I'll have auto resume of each video/live stream I select in my application. I was able to set the autoplay when I initialize a The current issue I have is that when I am trying to do it like below code it is not doing what I want (each time when I go with that app into background and resume it shows me the play button)

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener, YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    //private YouTubePlayer player = null;
    private boolean isFullscreen;
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Initializing YouTube Player View for displaying YouTube video **/
        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        player.setFullscreen(true);
        player.setOnFullscreenListener(this);

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.loadVideo(YouTubeVideoId.VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {
        this.isFullscreen = isFullscreen;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your kindly help and the advises!

Answer (score 1):

I have solution for you:

I had exactly the same problem and after jumping into the official provided examples I discovered, to my dismay, that they had exactly the same problem. External controls seemed to be unable to interact with the player in any significant way. Not to mention getting a fresh YoutubePlayer tends to be problematic. However I managed to discover something by testing and trying different things:

Even if you save a static reference to your YoutubePlayer this reference fails to change the player in any way. BUT you can still retrieve where the video  paused. So, the next logical step for me was to try this:

1. Getting the position from the player before leaving the activity:

   ```
   Integer myMILLIS = yplayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
   ```
2. Then, when coming back reload the video, and move it to the right position:

   ```
   // Reload the SAME VIDEO again (yplayer is the YoutubePlayer)
   yplayer.cueVideo(mVideoURL);
   // Get the position you saved back
   yplayer.seekToMillis(myMILLIS);
   // Start Playing the video from that position again
   yplayer.play();
   ```

The thing is, for some strange reason that alone does not work, but when I tried to debug the previous pieces of code... IT ENDED UP WORKING SOMETIMES.

So, after some more testing I discovered the problem with the previous solution: After calling

```
    yplayer.cueVideo(mVideoURL);
```

Calling anything else immediately after WILL FAIL. Therefore this might be a bizarre solution but it does work perfectly:

1. Getting the position from the player before leaving the activity:

   ```
   Integer myMILLIS = yplayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
   ```
2. Then, when coming back reload the video:

   ```
   // Reload the SAME VIDEO again (yplayer is the YoutubePlayer)
   yplayer.cueVideo(mVideoURL);
   ```
3. Before doing anything else, we have to wait a little:

   ```
   // The next pause is here to allow the video to load
   try
   {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e)
   {
       // Do something here if you need to
   }
   ```
4. Move it to the right position again, and play it:

   ```
   // Get the position you saved back
   yplayer.seekToMillis(myMILLIS);
   // Start Playing the video from that position again
   yplayer.play();
   ```

That solved my problem. I hope it solve yours.